# How to resize an mp4 video and reduce frame rate while keeping quality?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm trying to resize (keeping quality) and reduce frame rate to 30, I've seen various command but I'm having difficulty.

This seems to resize nicely

`ffmpeg -i final-video.mp4 -aspect 886:1920 -c copy final-resized.mp4`

I've also see `-r 30` and `-filter:v fps=fps=30`

But neither seem to work in-conjunction with the resize command.

I've seen posts like this 
[Re-sampling H264 video to reduce frame rate while maintaining high image quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004137/re-sampling-h264-video-to-reduce-frame-rate-while-maintaining-high-image-quality)
But this takes a long time.

Comment: You can change resolution without reencoding. And if youre reencoding, you should set a bitrate or crf value.

Comment: So can i change the resolution and bitrate without encoding, if so how?

Comment: No, you can’t. Changing the resolution and bitrate REQUIRES reencoding.

Comment: So whats the complete command line for that?

Comment: Although I can resize I cannot reduce the bitrate to 30.